# Split string from a string SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to take value from a string. Please see this example string format: `"(Fault Reported: Not Heating - POD - CC - We fit shower 2 years ago - Lime - €124.00 ) ( Job Report: Replaced Element & Stat. €149.00 paid CC 08/17)"`
I would like to select second parentheses value

```
 `(Job Report: Replaced Element & Stat. €149.00 paid CC 08/17)`
```

How could I achieved that? I tried below way but can't get the actual value.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)='(Fault Reported: Not Heating - POD - CC - We fit shower 2 years ago - Lime - €124.00 ) ( Job Report: Replaced Element & Stat. €149.00 paid CC 08/17) '
SELECT PARSENAME( REPLACE(@s,') (','.'),2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARSENAME()` is not the best choice here because there are other `<unknown number>` of `.` characters, which would need to be replaced first and then put back after, which gets messy fast.

How about:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(max) = '(Fault Reported: Not Heating - POD - CC - We fit '
  + 'shower 2 years ago - Lime - €124.00 ) ( Job Report: Replaced Element '
  + '& Stat. €149.00 paid CC 08/17) ';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX(') (', @s) + 2, 8000);
```

Result:

```
( Job Report: Replaced Element & Stat. €149.00 paid CC 08/17)
```

One example is almost never enough to provide the right solution, though. Lots of edge cases you probably haven't considered yet. The most glaring:

- What if there is only one set of parentheses? Do you want NULL, empty string, something else?
- What if there are more than two? Do you want everything 2+? Only the 2nd? Only the last? Something else?

Comment: Thank you so much , its work fine for me. My query like that SELECT SUBSTRING(ProbDesc, CHARINDEX(') (', ProbDesc) + 2, 8000) from servicerecords where SerRecID is not null.